# Sorting with isotope from external json rendered with handlebars

Tags: json, ajax, wordpress, handlebars.js, jquery-isotope

Can't seem to get Isotope sort to work :(

On the client side of a webpage I'm displaying data which comes from an external json with a template using handlebars.js.

I want the users to be able to sort, filter and search the data that is displayed. I've seen that with Isotope can this be achieve successfully. I did manage to get filtering to work.

However I'm stuck with sorting in targeting the class of the object with the getSortData option which value comes from the json.

Example of the JSON structure with the price:

[image]

Here is the code trying to sort by price, first my menu:

```
        <ul id="sort">
         <li><a href="#original-order" data-sort="original-order" class="selected">original order</a></li>
         <li><a href="#number" data-sort="number">number</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Then my handlebars template, where I want to reach the p.class = number:

```
    <div id="mcContainer"></div>

    <script id="mcTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

    {{#each this}} {{#annoncer}}
    <article class="mc_item {{category}} {{year}}">
        <a data-single href="{{id}}">
            <h3>{{brand}} {{model}}</h3>
            <img src={{images.0.small}} />
            <h4 class="mc_aar">ÅR: {{year}}, {{km}} km</h4>
            <p>{{category}}</p>
            <p class="mc_pris number">{{price}},-</p>
            <hr>
        </a>
    </article>
    {{/annoncer}} {{/each}}
</script>
```

And my javascript file:

```
(function ($) {

"use strict";

// javascript code here. i.e.: $(document).ready( function(){} );
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    var $container = $('#mcContainer');
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://diegovega.dk/kea/2semester/json-eks/json-eks.json",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            var template = $('#mcTemplate').html();
            var renderer = Handlebars.compile(template);
            var result = response;
            $('#mcContainer').html(renderer(result));
            runIsotope();
        }
    });

    function runIsotope() {
        var $items = $('.mc_item');
        $items.isotope({})
        $items.isotope('reloadItems')
            .isotope({
                itemSelector: '.mc_item',
                layoutMode: 'fitRows',
                fitRows: {
                    gutter: 20
                },
                getSortData: {
                    number: '.number parseInt'
                },
            });
        // Sort based on price
        $('#sort').on('click', function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
                $(this).removeClass('checked');
                    .isotope({
                        sortBy: 'original-order'
                    });
            } else {
                $('#sort').removeClass('checked');
                var sortValue = $(this).attr('data-sort-value');
                console.log($(this).attr('data-sort-value'));
                    .isotope({
                        sortBy: sortValue
                    });
                $(this).addClass('checked');
            }
        });
    } //RUN ISOTOPE
}); // END DOCUMENT READY
})(jQuery); // END use strict
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Initialize Isotope on the container, not the items
Use data-sort attribute on the links click